# Relationship between air pollution and lung function and sleep disorders

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, complex-sentences

I wanted to discuss the relationship between air quality and lung function, and the relationship between air quality and sleep disorders, in one sentence. Is there any efficient way to combine the phrases? If I use "Relationship between air pollution and lung function and sleep disorders" is it understandable?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but please note that this site is oriented more to the analysis of the language itself; this is not a writers' workshop or proofreading service, so any request for help with phrasing must address a specific point of grammar or usage. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @Vin Although I have answered your question (and thanks for accepting it!), I suggest you take these kind of questions to https://writing.stackexchange.com/ where people with better writing skills than me may help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was understandable for me. You may want to write it using a comma like this:

> Relationship between air pollution, lung function and sleep disorder

PS:

- I think *sleep disordered* (as you mentioned in your question) is refering to a person who is suffering *sleep disorder*. If you want to use the name of this symptom, ***sleep disorder*** is correct.

Source:
Merriam-Webster dictionary's entry on the words: *between* & *disordered*